# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause (Nested SELECT, inner join)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my MS SQL Server Database: `Brand` and `Auto`.

`Brand` table contains information about auto brands. Here are the columns:
`BrandId`,
`BrandName`,
`BrandCountry`.

`Auto` table contains info about specific models. Columns:
`AutoId`,
`AutoModel`,
`BrandId`,
`Price`.

The relationship between both of tables could be illustrated like this:

```sql
Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
```

My goal is to show brand which has maximum average price of all the cars connected to this brand.
Here's the query that I use to show maximal average sum (and it works):

```
SELECT MAX(AverageSum) AS AverageSum
FROM (
        SELECT
            Brand.BrandName AS BrandName, (SUM(Price) / COUNT(Auto.BrandId)) AS AverageSum
        FROM
            Brand INNER JOIN Auto
        ON
            Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
        GROUP BY 
            Brand.BrandName) AS ChosenBrand
```

The problem is that it shows only a number, but I also need to display the brand name. I try to append the brand name (`ChosenBrand.BrandName`) to select query like this:

```
SELECT ChosenBrand.BrandName, MAX(AverageSum) AS AverageSum
FROM (
        SELECT
            Brand.BrandName AS BrandName, (SUM(Price) / COUNT(Auto.BrandId)) AS AverageSum
        FROM
            Brand INNER JOIN Auto
        ON
            Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
        GROUP BY 
            Brand.BrandName) AS ChosenBrand
```

And I get the error

> Column 'ChosenBrand.BrandName' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

If I append `GROUP BY` to the end of the query like this:

```
SELECT ChosenBrand.BrandName, MAX(AverageSum) AS AverageSum
FROM (
        SELECT
            Brand.BrandName AS BrandName, (SUM(Price) / COUNT(Auto.BrandId)) AS AverageSum
        FROM
            Brand INNER JOIN Auto
        ON
            Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
        GROUP BY 
            Brand.BrandName) AS ChosenBrand
GROUP BY 
            ChosenBrand.BrandName
```

it displays all the brands with average sums, but I need only one, which is max. How can I achieve this?

Please help with a proper MS SQL Server syntax to resolve the problem.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers, here is the solution for MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Brand.BrandName AS BrandName, (SUM(Price) / COUNT(Auto.BrandId)) AS AverageSum
FROM
    Brand INNER JOIN Auto
ON
    Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
GROUP BY 
    Brand.BrandName
ORDER BY
    AverageSum DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one row -- in the event of ties -- then use `ORDER BY` and limit the result set to one row.  In standard SQL this looks like:

```
SELECT b.BrandName AS BrandName, AVG(Price) AS avg_price
FROM Brand b INNER JOIN
     Auto a
     ON b.BrandId = a.BrandId
GROUP BY b.BrandName
ORDER BY avg_price DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Some databases use `LIMIT` or `SELECT TOP` to limit the result set to one row.

Notes:

- Table aliases makes queries easier to write and to read.  Use table name abbreviations.
- SQL has an aggregation function, `AVG()`, which does what you want.  You don't need the explicit division.