# Maximum price in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - `Brand` and `Auto`.

`Brand` contains information about auto brands. Here are the columns:

```
BrandId
BrandName
BrandCountry
```

`Auto` contains info about specific models. Columns:

```
AutoId
AutoModel
BrandId
Price
```

where `Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId`.

My task is to show a model of a car with a maximum price of each brand.

Here's the query that I use to show brand and maximum price without an auto model (and it works):

```
SELECT Brand.BrandName, MAX(Price)
FROM Brand 
INNER JOIN Auto ON Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
GROUP BY Brand.BrandName
```

The problem is that it does not show a model, and I also need to display the model name. I try to append it to select query like this:

```
SELECT Brand.BrandName, Auto.AutoModel, MAX(Price)
FROM Brand 
INNER JOIN Auto ON Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
GROUP BY Brand.BrandName
```

And I get the error

> Column 'Auto.AutoModel' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How can I achieve this?

Please help with the proper syntax for SQL Server to resolve the problem.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. What about the error don't you understand and we can elaborate.

Comment: You must add all columns (that are not in an aggregate function) to the group by clause. eg. `SELECT Brand.BrandName, Auto.AutoModel, MAX(Price)
FROM Brand INNER JOIN Auto
ON Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
GROUP BY Brand.BrandName, Auto.AutoModel`

Comment: This is also the error you had in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694511/column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-ag). You should take the time to understand the answers you have; otherwise you learn nothing.

Comment: ljcordero, if I put Automodel to Group By, the result will show the whole list with all the cars, and I need only those ones which have max price.
But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function for the table `Auto` to get the highest price for each `BrandId` and then join to `Brand`:

```
SELECT b.BrandName, a.AutoModel, a.Price
FROM Brand AS b INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BrandId ORDER BY Price DESC) rn
  FROM Auto
) AS a
ON b.BrandId = a.BrandId
WHERE a.rn = 1
```